# Better way to deal with "Only part of the message has been downloaded" mail warning?

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, stock-email-app

I'm using the stock e-mail app on Android 4.3.  This morning, when I tried to forward an e-mail to another person, I got a warning that popped up which read:

```
Only part of the message has been downloaded. 
If you continue, the rest of the original message may be lost.
```

I get the same warning if I try to reply to the message.  I tried pressing the "sync" icon above the message.  I tried waiting a while for the message to finish downloading.  I still got the warning.

I finally resolved the issue by scrolling all the way to the bottom of the message, but this is a rather bothersome solution, requiring time and lots of finger flicks. I don't see anything else that seems relevant to the problem at hand, but surely there must be some way better to resolve the problem?

Comment: What account type are you using for your mail account? The error IMHO only applies to POP (where messages are stored client-side and deleted from the server once downloaded). If my assumption is correct, switching to IMAP (messages are stored server-side, and only *cached* client-side) should solve your issue.

Comment: Strange. I'm using an IMAP account already.

Comment: @Izzy Double-checking my settings I found an option "Size to retrieve emails" which was set at 50kB.  I've upped it to "All"; guess I'll see if this makes any difference...

Comment: That makes no sense (I mean, the error message and IMAP). There should be nothing "lost", as the message stays stored on the server. Maybe you should use a different mail app then: I'm using K9, and have that setting on 25kB. No issues. That limit is there to save bandwidth; also it often makes not much sense to download all attachments to the device.